# JS/jQuery : Hiding elements which doesnt have a spesific attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="picture" picturename="picture of a horse and stuff"></div>
```

The code below will effectively hide all elements where attribute picturename contains "horse":

```
$('[picturename*="horse"]').hide();
```

But how do I hide all elements where attribute picturename DOESNT contain "horse"?
You would think adding a ! before the = would do the trick but no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.picture').not('[picturename*="horse"]').hide();
```

This should do.

Comment: thanks man. do you know if is it possible to use this for hiding picturenames which doesnt contain "horse" OR "dog"? like.. `$('.picture').not('[picturename*="horse" or "dog"]').hide();`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can use:

```js
$('.picture:not([picturename*="horse"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picture" picturename="picture of a horse and stuff">show</div>
<div class="picture" picturename="picture of a horse and stuff">show</div>
<div class="picture" picturename="picture of a and stuff">hide</div>
<div class="picture" picturename="picture of a horse and stuff">show</div>
```

After your last comment to hide when doesn't contain horse or dog you can use:

```
$('.picture:not([picturename*="horse"]):not([picturename*="dog"])').hide();
```

Comment: is it possible to use this for hiding picturenames which doesnt contain "horse" OR "dog"?
like..
`$('.picture:not([picturename*="horse" or "dog"])').hide();`

Comment: Yes you can use `$('.picture:not([picturename*="horse"]):not([picturename*="dog"])').hide();` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/LkLa5oux/1/)